# my fixed header does not overlap the other element

Tags: html, css, header

when I scroll down on my page, my container overlap the header, but I want  my header to overlap the container, so I made my header on a fixed position, but it does not work

here is my html code:

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header class="leheader">
      <div id="bloc1"></div>
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dm6H7GV.png">
      <div id="bloc2"></div>
    </header>
    <main class="container"></main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my css code:

```
body,
html,
.page {
  background: #666666;
  width: 99%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leheader {
  display: flex;
  width: 99%;
  position: fixed;
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: calc(100%-50px);
}

#bloc1 {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 0.5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 90px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

#bloc2 {
  background: #467491;
  margin-top: 4px;
  width: 93%;
  height: 37px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 57px;
  left: 9px;
  background: #cccccc;
  width: 99%;
  height: calc(100% - 33px);
}
```

where is the problem ?

Comment: Because the container is positioned as well, it overlaps the header on the z-axis. You need to set a higher `z-index` for the header.

Comment: Ah, thank you it works, you saved my time ! have a good day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the z-index property to the header.

like this....

z-index: 2

Comment: you can use any value above 1 for the z-index

Answer (score 0):

In CSS to make something Fixed position you also need to give it a z-index (which is its position on z-axis). Read more about [Z-Index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) here. Apart from it you also have to give it a position in terms of top, left, bottom and left to tell it where it has to fixed.

```
.leheader {
  display: flex;
  width: 99%;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:2;
  flex: 1 100%;
  height: calc(100%-50px);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will read more about it, i didn't knew it before